# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::enablePostgis()

Tags: php, database, symfony, postgis

I'm trying to setup a Laravel app. I made sure i got postgis installed on my systme using brew:

```
$ brew install postgis
Warning: postgis 2.3.2 is already installed
```

and i know it’s already listed as one of the required packages in `composer.json` like so:

```
"phaza/laravel-postgis": "^3.0",
```

I can find it in my `composer.lock` as well.

yet when i run `php artisan migrate` I get this

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::enablePostgis()
```

my code looks something like this

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            ...
            $table->enablePostgis();
```

If I click on the jump to definition on `enablePostgis` it takes me here:

```
vendor/phaza/laravel-postgis/src/Schema/Blueprint.php
```

Not sure what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that my postgres db connection details (ie username/pwd) were incorrect! So it had nothing to do with importing libraries.. so the error message was so misleading.. sorry guys :(

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
```

with

```
use Phaza\LaravelPostgis\Schema\Blueprint;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just putting eg `$table->point('location')` in `function up()`
 without `$table->enablePostgis()`?

In the example migration in [the documentation](https://github.com/njbarrett/laravel-postgis), there is no `$table->enablePostgis()` statement anywhere.

Comment: Oh - and I suggest you also fix the `use` statement as per @cthulu's commet.